# Get wax off of wooden table

Tags: cleaning, furniture

I tend to burn a lot of candles, and every once in awhile some wax will spill onto my coffee table.

Are there any Life hacks to get this wax off nicely and completely?

Everything I've tried (windex, scraping, rubbing alch.) has always left at least some residue behind.  The table isn't the nicest but I would like the solution to not cause any damage to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an ice cube to completely harden the wax. Then scrape it off with something plastic. (Old credit card, used gift card, plastic putty knife, etc.)

[Source](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/article/0,,20318511,00.html)

Comment: great! i was thinking of trying to heat it up but never thought to cool it down ;)

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to heat it. It could be done with, for example, fan ([wikihow](http://m.wikihow.com/Remove-Candle-Wax), [thriftyfun](http://www.thriftyfun.com/tf844046.tip.html), [yahoo](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120417211222AAN9UEH)). Then wipe the wax with something not really valuable, e.g. paper towels.

Instead of fan wikihow also advices to use iron: put some cloth on your wax, iron it with low power, wipe the wax, wash your cloth (or just use paper towels again).